# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column does not exist

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am getting the below error when i am trying to make a query to the database via python.roll_no is the key as per the table.

```
File "class_room.py", line 30, in get
cursor.execute("select first_name from class_room where keyword=%s",     (roll_no))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "keyword" does not exist
LINE 1: select first_name from class_room where keyword='3'


                                           ^
12:21 class_room=# \d+ class_room
                               Table "public.class_room"
  Column   |  Type   |         Modifiers         | Storage  | Stats target |   Description
------------+---------+---------------------------+----------+--------------+-      ------------
roll_no    | integer | not null                  | plain    |              |
first_name | text    | not null default ''::text | extended |              |
last_name  | text    | not null default ''::text | extended |              |
marks      | integer |                           | plain    |              |
Indexes:
   "class_room_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (roll_no)
Has OIDs: no



user:~/pathclass_room $ cat schema.sql
create table class_room (
roll_no int primary key,
first_name text not null default '',
last_name text not null default '',
marks int
);
```

Comment: What is `keyword` ? You don't have such column.

Comment: Like @sagi wrote above. Sometimes I have similar error when I use `' '` instead `" "` and vice versa in string of sql query. But here it seems You do not have the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
cursor.execute("select first_name from class_room where roll_no = %s", (roll_no,))
```

Do not omit the comma after `roll_no`. It turns the parenthesised expression into a tuple.

Comment: Thanks , That helped.